# My Recursive method has a stackoverflow when used with a particular dataset

Tags: c#, recursion, stack-overflow, iteration

I am trying to search a List for combinations that add up to a particular value (I've tried using Knapsack but it was checking too much for my particular scenario and taking too long). The code works and finds matches for most of the datasets I throw at it but fails for some others.

All of my List s don't have more that 100 entries.

I had assumed that because my recursive method is wrapped in a sensible if statement that a stack overflow would not occur but it blows up on this line: if(x.Sum(y => y.Amount) == limit)

Here is my code:

```
    private static void Check(List<double> trackedListToCopy, double limit)
    {
        List<CheckerObject> trackedList = new List<CheckerObject>();
        int idCount = 1;
        trackedListToCopy.ForEach(x => {
            trackedList.Add(new CheckerObject() { Amount = x, Id = idCount});
            idCount++;
        });
        List<List<CheckerObject>> possiblitiesToCheck = new List<List<CheckerObject>>();
        if (trackedList.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Amount == limit) != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exact match found");
            return;
        }
        trackedList.ForEach(item =>
        {
            var listToCheck = new List<CheckerObject>();
            if (trackedList.First().Id == item.Id)
                return;
            listToCheck.Add(trackedList.First());
            listToCheck.Add(item);
            possiblitiesToCheck.Add(listToCheck);
            if (possiblitiesToCheck.Any(x => x.Sum(y => y.Amount) == limit))
            {
                List<CheckerObject> match = possiblitiesToCheck.First(x => x.Sum(y => y.Amount) == limit);
                Console.WriteLine("Match found with 2 entries" + match);
                return;
            }
        });
        var baseList = new List<List<CheckerObject>>(possiblitiesToCheck);
        SubsequentCheck(baseList, trackedList, limit);
    }

    private static void SubsequentCheck(List<List<CheckerObject>> baseList, List<CheckerObject> trackedList, double limit)
    {
        //List<List<CheckerObject>> copy = new List<List<CheckerObject>>(baseList);
        trackedList.ForEach(item => {
            baseList.ForEach(x =>{
                if (!x.Contains(item))
                {
                    x.Add(item);
                    if(x.Sum(y => y.Amount) == limit)
                    {
                        string show = "";
                        x.ForEach(n => { show += n.Amount + ","; });
                        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Match Found from {0}", show));
                    }
                    if (x.Sum(y => y.Amount) < limit)
                    {
                        SubsequentCheck(new List<List<CheckerObject>>(baseList), trackedList, limit);
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    }

    public class CheckerObject 
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public double Amount { get; set; }
    }
```

Any and all help is as always greatly appreciated.

Comment: If SubsequentCheck ever calls itself (i.e. `x.Sum(y => y.Amount) < limit` evaluates to true) it will then cause a stack overflow as you are passing in the same values as it is called with in the first place, so it will then call itself forever.

Comment: I expect this to happen, the reason for this is that I add a new item to the list every time we recursively call this method so eventually my if statement will evaluate to false and the method will not call itself

Comment: No problems are staring me in the face. I would throw some `Console.WriteLine()` statements at it.

Comment: thanks @500-InternalServerError, I've tried adding some WriteLines but there are too many to make sense of, I've tried wrapping the initial call of SubsequentCheck() in a try catch but it doesn't catch my stackoverflow exception. Could it be to do with the method being static?

Comment: The method being static should have no influence on this. If you get too much data try reducing the test problem to something smaller until it works properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
private static void SubsequentCheck(List<List<CheckerObject>> baseList, List<CheckerObject> trackedList, double limit)
```

to

```
private static void SubsequentCheck(List<List<CheckerObject>> baseList, List<CheckerObject> trackedList, double limit, int recursiveDepth = 0)
```

and

```
 if (x.Sum(y => y.Amount) < limit)
 {
          SubsequentCheck(new List<List<CheckerObject>>(baseList), trackedList, limit);
 }
```

to

```
 if (x.Sum(y => y.Amount) < limit)
  {
         SubsequentCheck(new List<List<CheckerObject>>(baseList), trackedList, limit, recursiveDepth + 1);
   }
```

Then log everything or put a conditional breakpoint on recursive depth greater than some sensible limit.

Also change the .ForEach calls to foreach loops so that the loop can be stopped properly for efficiency (the return statement does not end the loop in this case)

Also change the Lists for Hashsets when calling .Contains so frequently if performance is an issue

Comment: Just changing the .ForEach to a regular foreach was enough to stop the stackoverflow. I didn't realise it made that much of a performance hit! Thanks god I don't have to thread up the method call to provide a larger stack size. Cheers Bro

Comment: .ForEach is the bane of my existence at the moment. Linq is a query syntax, and isn't so clear when used for processing at the same time. 
I put a "max depth / iterations" in all my potentially never ending loops

Comment: Also that "return" within the foreach was acting more like a "continue" so make sure the functionality is what you want now that the proper foreach has been inserted

Comment: yeah, I had 2 'tracker' variables in there, a trackedList and a trackedDepth but I got rid of them as it was muddying the waters when I was trying to refactor. I was only looking at the .ForEach vs foreach the other day but the only thing I found was someone saying there is a performance hit of around 50% but totally forgot about it when writing this.